# Why is this php array not getting anything?

Tags: php

I'm trying to submit a 'defacto' option array (although it looks like a search bar) to a php file and show the results that I sent. This is what it looks like now:

[image]
Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b30QE.png

And so what I did was that I changed the submit.php from this:

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['$_REQUEST']))
{
  $aVenues = $_POST['select3'];

  if(!isset($aVenues))
  {
    echo("<p>You didn't select any venues!</p>\n");
  }
  else
  {
    $nVenues = count($aVenues);

    echo("<p>You selected $nVenues venues: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $nVenues; $i++)
    {
      echo($aVenues[$i] . " ");
    }
    echo("</p>");
  }
}

?>
```

[Here's a link to the page](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/autocompletejquery/), and as you can see the submit.php shows an empty page, why is this :/ ?
Thank youu :)

Comment: $_POST['$_REQUEST'] <-- that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if(isset($_POST['select3']))
```

Not what you have at the moment. That index won't exist in $_POST.

Comment: Whaaaaaa, I never thought I would get this to work :)))))))) I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Thank you Jon :))))))))

Answer (score 1):

the if

```
if(isset($_POST['$_REQUEST']))
```

fails.

$_REQUEST and $_POST are both different arrays, 1 containing only POST data, the other combining POST and GET.

The check should be (I assume)

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST)) { }
```

To verify that data actually has been posted to the server.